# How to switch between VM guest and host in Windows 10 with single keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm looking for simple solution for switching between host and guest on Windows 10 with VirtualBox (5.x).

Let's say I have two virtual desktops open, one containing VM guest window in full screen mode. I'd like to switch from desktop with VM window to another.

**It can be done with combining two shortcuts**: `right ctrl` (for unfocusing VM window) and `ctrl`+`wind`+`right/left` (for changing virtual desktop).

Is there any option for doing this with **single keyboard shortcut**? similarly to how it can be done on macbooks.

Comment: You're going to need a keystoke that doesn't go to vitrualbox even when it has keyboard focus. or else fon't give virtualbox keyboard focus in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

As the right ctrl key is very rarely used, a keyboard mapper could be used.

Set the right crl key as a combination of itself and ctrl+win+left/right

Search online for keyboard mapper programs, which are available for both Windows and MacOS.